# Increase worker dyno on Heroku to use with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have been operating under 0 workers, but need to increase the speed at which I'm processing background tasks. I am using Sidekiq for all of my background workers.

When I increase the worker dyno count to 1, I keep getting this error in my heroku logs:

`dont know how to build task 'jobs:work'`

From researching this, it seems like the issue is that heroku worker dynos are reliant on `delayed_job` and I am not using `delayed_job` anywhere.

If I install `delayed_job`, what will I have to change to get sidekiq to work? Or do I even need `delayed_job`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your projects Procfile to specify sidekiq for the worker:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Then redeploy your application.

I think Heroku defaults to trying to run delayed_job if you don't specify the worker in your Procfile.